# JavaScript development and production mode

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

What is the best way to setup javaScript app settings for local (development) and production mode. Ex, I have different REST API links on my local machine and on the server. I can solve it by moving this setting into a different settings file and gitignore it.
It there any other possible solution for it? var debug mode = true?
What is the best practice? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you've already noted, one option is simply to have:

```
window.IS_DEBUG = true;
```

somewhere and then check:

```
if(window.IS_DEBUG){ ...
```

Rather than hard-coding it though, another option would be to calculate it on load, by looking at the URL.  For example:

```
$(function() {
    window.IS_DEBUG = window.location.indexOf('localhost') != -1;
    // Start the rest of your code
});
```

The advantage of this later approach is that you don't need to git-ignore any files (or have separate files at all).